# Invoke in Class in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, class, invoke

I have a thread running in a class that needs to update value of textbox but invoke does not appear in class.

Any idea how to do it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using CheckedBoxSerpCrawler;
namespace SERP_Crawler
{   
    class Crawl
    {
        public Crawl()
        {              

        var t = new Thread(() =>
              {
                 for (int i = 2; i < (pagesToScroll / 10); i++)
                  {
                        //Here i need to invoke CheckUrlList
                  } 
              });
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();          

        }//End Constructor
    private void CheckUrlList(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Here update textbox
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What type of class is it? a user control / form?

Comment: We really need more information, what's exactly your problem etc. - maybe you even want to show us some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliSense shows this without any problems. I don't know what problem you have?

```
        TextBox test = new TextBox();
        if (test.InvokeRequired)
        {
            test.BeginInvoke(...);
        }
```

The above mentioned should work, maybe you should have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx

**Edit:** To clarify a few things - `test`is here your TextBox which value is ought to be changed. If you don't have access to the TextBox in your class, I like using events to start a method in your gui-control-class. But that's another story ;)

Comment: The class might not be the form or might not inherit from `Control`.

Comment: That doesn't mean that he can't get the control. You just need to have access to the Control.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call Invoke on the textbox, not on the class that wants to update the textbox.  If you look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) for Invoke:

> Executes the specified delegate on the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle.

then you can see that it is the thread that the textbox is running on that is important.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this textbox is on a form, so add a method to the form that takes a string as a parameter, then inside this method use `Invoke` to set the textbox's value.  Inside your class, call this method on the form.

Answer (score 0):

If you want for your class to provide some notification mechanism, what you really want is an *event*, not to update a UI directly. In the context of a WinForms app, you can *handle* this event from your form and perform any `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` work there.

Hopefully that makes sense. If not, try looking up .NET events to understand how they work.

But by all means, keep your class decoupled from your user interface. I'm not sure why anyone would encourage a move in the opposite direction.